# Json to pojo online converter splits json to different classes

Tags: java, json

I have my json:

```
{
  "title": "Regular Python Developer",
  "street": "Huston 10",
  "city": "Miami",
  "country_code": "USA",
  "address_text": "Huston 10, Miami",
  "marker_icon": "python",
  "workplace_type": "remote",
  "company_name": "Merixstudio",
  "company_url": "http://www.merixstudio.com",
  "company_size": "200+",
  "experience_level": "mid",
  "latitude": "52.4143773",
  "longitude": "16.9610657",
  "published_at": "2020-04-21T10:00:07.446Z",
  "remote_interview": true,
  "id": "merixstudio-regular-django-developer",
  "employment_types": [
    {
      "type": "b2b",
      "salary": {
        "from": 8000,
        "to": 13500,
        "currency": "usd"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "permanent",
      "salary": {
        "from": 6500,
        "to": 11100,
        "currency": "usd"
      }
    }
  ],
  "company_logo_url": "https://bucket.justjoin.it/offers/company_logos/thumb/07dd4eaf9a6ffb6b85bd03c5bd5c95016d5804ce.png?1628853121",
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "REST",
      "level": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Python",
      "level": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Django",
      "level": 4
    }
  ],
  "remote": true
}
```

Online json to pojo converter splits this to 4 Classes. I have a problem with `Salary`.
I need `Salary` class to be not  separated from `Root`it's needs to be inside`Root` class.
How should `Root` class looks like?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can nest classes:

```
class Root {
  String title;
  List<EmpType> employmentTypes;

  class EmpType {
    String type;
    Salary salary;

    class Salary {
      int from;
      int to;
    }
  }
}
```

In practice the difference to creating separate files for each class is often neglegible. The main purpose is to have stronger encapsulation or to group classes that belong together.

You could look at the source code of for example [`java.util.ImmutableCollections`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java) for a scenario where this makes sense. There are several nested classes that belong together and should not be accessible from anywhere else.

### EDIT: Filter by `salary.from`:

```
// given:
List<EmpType> employmentTypes = ...;

List<EmpType> filtered = employmentTypes.stream()
  .filter(et -> et.salary.from > 3000);
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### EDIT 2:

```
// given:
List<Root> roots = ...;

List<Root> filtered = roots.stream()
    .filter(r -> r.employmentTypes.stream()
        .anyMatch(e -> e.salary.from > 3000))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What is the path to access "int from" in Salary class ?

Comment: In this example it would be `root.employmentType.get(int).salary.from`. But in general you can place a `getSalary` method anywhere you like and access it that way.

Comment: I need filter like salary.from>3000

Comment: I've added an example to the answer

Comment: Path doesn;t work because I have list of <Root> objects not <EmpType>

Comment: Really so hard? I'll add another example... Next time please provide some more meaningful information in your question.

Comment: Now I have nullPointer on .filter(r -> r.employmentTypes.stream()

Comment: Maybe because you didn't set a value for `employmentTypes` in your root object